# How can I open a high chart in a modal window when the chart is clicked on?

Tags: highcharts

New to high charts and javascript and want to know how to open up a new modal window of that chart when per a click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take look at click event on chart.

```
 chart: {
        events: {
            click: function(event) {
                alert ('x: '+ event.xAxis[0].value +', y: '+
                      event.yAxis[0].value);
            }
        }        
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vqCMA/

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.click

Comment: Thanks! That's the hook I need. However, I'm definitely not a js guru but is there an example of how I could populate chart into a modal window itself?

Comment: You can use jquery plugins or prepare div with position absolute and dipslay none, and in click event use show() function